# How to customize a div's scroll bar with css modules?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

I'm trying to customize a div component's scroll bar like this :

Home.js

```
import classes from "./Home.module.scss";
function Home() {
  return (
    <div className={classes.scroll}>
      <p>jasbdkajsdb</p>
      <p>jasbdkajsdb</p>
      <p>jasbdkajsdb</p>
      <p>jasbdkajsdb</p>
      <p>jasbdkajsdb</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Home.module.scss

```
.scroll {
  &:-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 20px;
  }
  &:-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: red;
    border-radius: 25px;
  }

  &::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

But the css doesn't apply . How can I customize a div's scrollbar ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a colon on two of your selectors try this:

**`Home.module.scss`**

```css
.scroll {
  &::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5px;
  }
  &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: red;
    border-radius: 25px;
  }

  &::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

[See the full list of scrollbar pseudo-element selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar#css_scrollbar_selectors)